# Add postfix fail2ban filter for incorrect auth

Tags: postfix, fail2ban

I'm trying to add a failregex for Postfix to catch systems sending no correct auth commands.

If I receive a line like this:

```
disconnect from unknown[ADDRESS] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
```

I'm looking for that `auth=0/1` part specifically and would like fail2ban to catch this. I'm using the default postfix filter and trying to amend to it and tried adding the following to it:

```
mdpr-failauth = disconnect
mdre-failauth = ^from .*[^[]\[<HOST>\] .*(auth=0/[0-9]+)+.*$
```

This seems to catch every disconnect line regardless if I have an `auth=0/[0-9]+`, `auth=1`, or no `auth` line in there at all. What exactly am I doing incorrectly here?